# No internet connection after updates

Tags: internet

I have installed some updates on my 14.04 after restarting the wired connection could be established but no internet access.
`ifconfig` shows me an IP adress 192.168.0.199. I tried to ping 192.168.0.1 but no received packets. Here some outputs, sorry its not formated I had the write this on my phone:

IFCONFIG:

```
eth0     Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 28:d2:44:39:f7:98 
inet addr:192.168.0.199 Bcast:192.168.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 
inet6 addr: fe80::2ad2:44ff:fe39:f798/64 Scope:Link 
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 
RX packets:77 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
TX packets:787 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:8009 (8.0 KB) TX bytes:86830 (86.8 KB) 

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback 
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1 
RX packets:631 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
TX packets:631 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
RX bytes:49459 (49.4 KB) TX bytes:49459 (49.4 KB) 

wlan0    Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 0c:8b:fd:7c:0b:f5 
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 
carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

ROUTE: 
Kernel IP routing table

```
Destination Gateway     Genmask       Flags Metric Ref Use Iface 
default     192.168.0.1 0.0.0.0       UG    0      0   0   eth0 
192.168.0.0 *           255.255.255.0 U     1      0   0   eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wired connection is getting that IP address from somewhere, either static or handed out by DHCP.

It is unusual, though not impossible, for your address to be 192.168.0.xxx. Linksys routers default to 192.168.1.1 and yield addresses 192.168.1.xxx. Other manufacturers will have something different from the first "1" usually.

In any event, check to see what the base address is of whatever router you are using and ensure that your IP address has the same first 3 fields the same. Do this either via DHCP or a static address.

Otherwise you are not on the same network and you will get the type of results you are indicating.

Comment: How do I check the base address? Note I don't have access to the router itself!